# PHP's include_path - set it to an empty string doesn't work

Tags: php, include-path

I have Apache HTTP Server v2.2 with PHP in FastCGI communication.

I tried to edit the `include_path` variable in `php.ini` to an empty string but it didn't work,
the path remains: `.:/usr/local/lib/php` (as seen by phpinfo()).
If I set the include path to a colon (`:`), then the include path finally changes.

How can I set it to an empty string?

Thank you.

Comment: Unsetting `include_path` would effectively disable includes, unless you're going to hard-code your app's path everywhere.

Comment: why are you trying to blank it?

Comment: @sdolgy: Because each user is restricted to a certain directory, which makes `include_path` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value has to be something besides an empty string.  If you don't want PHP to include anything from anywhere, you can set it to some nonexistent path (and let it fail to find the path when it tries to include stuff).  It's not an ideal solution, but it'll work.

I have a feeling you're going about this wrong, though.  `include_path` is extremely useful, unless you intend to hard-code your app's path everywhere (which is a bad idea in itself, IMO).  If you set it to just `.`, that should be enough to get rid of paths that shouldn't be in there, while keeping it practical to `include` stuff.

Comment: Please see my reply to `sdolgy` above. What's wrong with using a PHP constants in order to help include files in my app? It's a normal routine, happens in every system that I see (e.g. IPB, vBulletin). Anyway, each user has the ability to modify the `include_path` value. I'm just the administrator that resets the initial values.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an app having a constant for its path, if the initial value won't work.  (Ideally, an app won't have its path hard-coded in -- it can find the path using `dirname(__FILE__)` in the app root.  But that's another topic.)  The initial value should be something reasonable and useful, though.  If it were somehow set to nothing, then every app -- no matter how trivial -- would need to either set its include path or specify a full path from the root in order to include anything.  Feels like a bad balance of "security" vs functionality, esp if your real security works.

Answer (score 0):

Now that there is more context behind the question.  This is more of a sysadmin question, but here's the response:

Per virtual host you can configure specific php.ini settings:

For apache:  https://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Now, if you aren't applying this to virtual hosts, and it's per user, I'm more then certain this is possible under the user public_html configurations.

Comment: Thanks, but PHP isn't a module of Apache.