# Disabling include_path in PHP

Tags: php, include-path

I'm looking for a way to disable PHP's use of `include_path` in a project.

### Background

Perhaps you're surprised: Why would I want to prevent the use of such a useful feature?

Unfortunately, while I'd consider the answer simple, it's not simple to accurately describe:

In brief, `include_path` is (obviously) package-/library-blind.

More specifically, it's possible to put two different versions of a library into two folders, both of which are in `include_path`, and ending up with executed code that is a *mixture* of both. Consider the following setting:

```
include_path=/some/server/path/lib:
    /var/www/apache/htdocs/yourApplication/library
```

Now imagine the canonical location for a library you want to use is in `/some/server/path/lib` and your build process places it there, but a developer is trying to patch a part of it and erroneously syncing the library to `/var/www/apache/htdocs/yourApplication/library`. Now imagine this happens:

```
/some/server/path/lib/moduleYouWant
    '--> A.php (old version)
/var/www/apache/htdocs/yourApplication/
    '--> SomeFile.php (uses B.php from module; previously used A.php)
/var/www/apache/htdocs/yourApplication/library/moduleYouWant
    '--> A.php (new version)
    '--> B.php (new file; uses A.php from module)
```

Suddenly, your application will mysteriously use or autoload (if your autoloader puts `include_path` to use, which most framework-supplied autoloaders do, as far as I'm aware) only *half* of the changes you made - the new `B.php` but the old `A.php`.

You may, of course, object to the setup I've described on grounds that it should never happen for other reasons. That's fair. I'm likely to agree, even. The above scenario is a backwards-incompatible change, for example, and that's not very nice.

Nonetheless, so far I've seen it happen twice in the wild (in a sufficiently complex project, with `chroot`s muddying the water) and it's eaten up *countless* confused debugging hours... and I don't want to have that issue again. Not in this sort of constellation - or any other.

I don't want PHP magically trying to find my files. I want PHP to demand I be *specific* about which files to load.

### Why I don't need include_path

With `__DIR__` (or `dirname(__FILE__)` in older PHP versions), *semantically* 'relative' paths are easy to construct. And if I need live- and test-server distinctions, constants defining absolute locations are my friend.

So... I want non-absolute paths supplied to `include()` (and related functions) to fail.

**[This stackoverflow question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753746/phps-include-path-set-it-to-an-empty-string-doesnt-work) tells me that I can't blank `include_path`. Is there perhaps some other way I can disable the feature?** My Googlefu is weak, but nonetheless I have a creeping suspicion the answer is 'no (unless you patch PHP itself)'.

If someone knows of a way I can put a stop to this other than by code convention agreement (or the related "*please don't use `include()` but this custom function I wrote*"), I'd love to know. :)

Comment: And setting it to a non-existing path as suggested in the linked question?

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: Apparently `.` is always part of the `include_path`, whether you try to remove it or not. :(

Comment: Why is that a problem? If you install all your libraries in the docroot and use absolute paths only, would that fix your problem?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Yes - and I do want to use absolute paths only. I just want PHP to reject non-absolute paths so situations like the one described can't occur. Basically, I want a way to mark non-absolute `include()`s as an 'error' or at least as a 'warning'... something that lets the developer know that what they are doing is not okay/accepted. Code convention can help a lot there (and is the current way I'm 'solving' this), but having a mechanism would be even better.

Comment: Why are you still writing your own includes? I thought you mentioned something about autoloading. Clever autoloading will make it so you never need to manually include anything. You could always put some processing on a pre-commit-hook of your versioning system that tries to find relative includes and blocks the commit, but this seems more of a 'culture' problem.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Yeah, I agree... it _is_ a bit of a culture problem. We have some places where includes are in use - mostly in cronjob scripts. A pre-commit-hook is definitely an option, but ultimately, I was hoping for a PHP-side way of handling this. As someone who's worked with application security before, I'm a bit obsessed with self-contained solutions if they can be arranged. In this case, there is probably no self-contained solution, though... which is okay, but I figured I'd ask in case there was. :)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Actually, can you write that as an answer? Because it does look like there's not just some setting or switch or trick I'm missing, and then that _would_ be the canonical way of dealing with it (and thus the right answer to my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate that the root of the problem is that you have developers writing bad relative includes where they should use be using absolute includes or autoloading.

The solution to this is not technical but cultural. You can enforce correct behavior by adding a pre-commit-hook to your versioning-system that tries to detect erroneous includes (either relative includes, or just all includes) and block the commit.

Comment: It's a shame there doesn't seem to be a technical way to enforce it, but then this really is the right way to approach the issue. Accepted. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following:

```
set_include_path("./");
```

then when you need to include file outside the current folder you have to specify the fully qualified relative or absolute path

Comment: I don't want relative paths to work for `.`, either, though. `.` in `include_path` is the working directory (AFAIK), not `__DIR__`; and it seems like `.` is always part of the `include_path`, whether one wants it to be or not.